# LINQ query custom Object best practice in EF 6.1

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I am using EF 6.1 with visual studio 2013. I have a View Model

```
public class SaprePartsViewModel
{
    public long ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

And also has database table `SapreParts` with same column name.

I have done this two method to fetch custom objects

i.

```
var sqlQueryList = db.Database.SqlQuery<SaprePartsViewModel>(
    "select ItemID,ItemCode,ItemName from SpareParts").ToList();
```

ii.

```
 var linqQueryList = db.SpareParts.Select(x => new SaprePartsViewModel
        {
            ItemID = x.ItemID,
            ItemCode = x.ItemCode,
            ItemName = x.ItemName
        }).ToList();
```

Both query is working fine.But my question is which one to use ?Which is optimal for performance?

Comment: i think performance is such a difficult topic to pin down as there are so many metrics involved. for the simple query above, the obvious answer is to use the EF convention as you get intellisense for free, plus makes testing a breeze. static strings as per the sql query will break over time and the body of the query can change over time too, so you have a moving target with option i - go for #ii unless you have measurable issues

Comment: run both cars on racetrack to find which one moves faster

Comment: ShekharPankaj - performance is not just about speed (imho). it's also about clarity of purpose and ease of maintenance. there's an old saying here in scotland *more haste, less speed*. in a nutshell, balance out the implications of shaving a few milliseconds from a query vs getting working code out the door and being easily maintained.

Comment: It`s probably better to use second approach, otherwise you can use first approach with the dapper - and it would be faster.

Comment: go with the second, strings are almost always a bad idea :). Also use scopes to handle the disposing after your query returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[as per my comments on OP]**

I think performance is such a difficult topic to pin down as there are so many metrics involved. For the simple query above, the obvious answer is to use the EF convention as you get intellisense for free, plus makes testing a breeze.

Static strings as per the sql query will break over time (bad, bad, bad!!) and the body of the query can change over time too (worse, worse, worse), so you have a moving target with option i - go for ii unless you have measurable issues.

As an aside, performance is not just about speed (imho), it's also about clarity of purpose and ease of maintenance. There's an old saying here in scotland *more haste, less speed*. In a nutshell, balance out the implications of shaving a few milliseconds from a query vs getting working code out the door and being easily maintained. Your team will thank you (as will you yourself over time)

Comment: if you read in detail, Jeff states the following: *Let's do the math, even though I suck at it. Each uncompiled run of the query took less than one third of a millisecond longer.* - So the take away here is that on average, you'd save 1/3 of a millisecond by sacrificing maintainability, readability and testability of using linq queries. your call :)